# Google Play: Receive SMS permission

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've sent one apk to the store and in the console, in necessary permissions section i see android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS and I don't have this permission in my manifest.

Anyone knows what can be triggering this permission?

In manifest I only have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="*******.fileprovider.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using some library that asks for this permission.

In Android Studio, open your manifest and check the "Merged Manifest" tab at the bottom. This will show you the final manifest after merging all dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @Idan with that I could see the problem.
Now, if I add this line, it will be removed? 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />